# Can't reuse function parameters

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to reuse function parameters some thing like this

```
fun test(i: Int) {
    i += 5
}
```

but as noted in [this distinction](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/function-parameters-are-val-not-var/897)

> Function parameters are `val` not `var`

Comment: Really, it's typically considered bad practice to modify arguments. I'd create a new variable with a different name, assign it to the parameter, then use it. Also, can you declare the parameter as a `var`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate  You can't designate function parameters as val/var in Kotlin.They are implied to be `val`.

Comment: why it is considered a bad practice I don't want to change the parameter in the outer scope just to avoid assign it. I think assign is more confusing,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kotlin, function arguments are treated as `val`. That means you'll have to do something inside your function in order to "modifty" its reference.

Your solution will work, but I feel that it's a bad practice to shadow variables. It leads to confusion, and doesn't quite accurately cover the intent that you understand that the effect is local to the function.

I would go with something like this:

```
fun test(i: Int) {
    var i2 = i
    i2 += 3 // etc...
}
```

Comment: I have considered it,  but in my case, the parameter names are width and height.
 and I feel renaming it would lead to less readable code.

Answer (score 0):

the only solution I found is to use name shadowing i.e something like that

```
fun test(i: Int) {
    var i = i
    i += 5
}
```

---

I'm not sure if it the best solution because it doesn't feel right, even  IntelliJ IDEA warns me about it.

I was hoping for thing magical like

```
fun test(var i: Int) {
    i += 5
}
```

but unfortuantly this doesn't even comile.

Comment: that's interesting Kotlin can define variables with duplicated parameter name. maybe it is a bug. +1

Comment: No, it's not, it's only a bad practice.

Comment: thanks, I got it. but you can't define any shadow variable in Java. In fact, Kotlin defined another local variable for that, you also can change the local variable type, e.g: `var i:String = "foo"`.